# Examples of problems in "theory-building" that reduce to "essentially combinatorics"

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

In Timothy Gowers excellent [paper](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/2cultures.pdf) "The Two Cultures of Mathematics" he writes:

> I have occasionally heard mathematicians on the theory side complain of a
>   problem that it has been attacked with all the known tools, but that a stubborn core remains which is “essentially combinatorics”.

I am interested if anyone can provide some examples of problems (solved or unsolved) in abstract areas (or using Gowers' terminology "on the theory side") of mathematics that have been reduced to a combinatorial problem. By "combinatorial" I mean in the same, admittely vague, way that Gowers used the word in his paper.

Specfically, has there been an open problem in a "theory-building" field that has been shown to follow from an open problem in a "problem-solving" field?

I apologize if this is too vague of a question and perhaps I simply misinterpretated what Gowers was talking about in his article.

Thanks.

Comment: Most of the representation theory of Lie groups is reduced to combinatorics. I would say that unless your theory has *not* been reduced to combinatorics (or arithmetic) then you do not understand it well.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm confused by the double negative "*unless* your theory has *not*". Did you mean to say "unless your theory has" = "if your theory has not", or did you really mean "if your theory has"?

Answer (score 0):

I think that Gowers gives excellent examples within the essay of combinatorics felling problems with surprising ease. This is what pages $5$ through $9$ of the essay are about. I will specifically highlight Erdos' Probabilistic Method as one of the most fundamentally groundbreaking ideas in combinatorics ever developed.